# Django/React 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: reactjs, django, forms, django-rest-framework, submit

I'm getting `POST http://localhost:8000/api/reports/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)` when I try to submit the form from React and I don't understand what's the problem.

Here's the code.

`models.py`

```py
class Report(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.TextField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    reporter_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reporter_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reporter_email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reporter_phone = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    report_image_1 = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    report_image_2 = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    report_image_3 = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

I also tried to put default values for images, but I still get the error.

`serializers.py`

```py
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categoryName = CategorySerializer(many=False, read_only=True, source='category')

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`

```py
class ManageReports(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(Report, id=id)

    def get_queryset(self):        
        return Report.objects.all()
```

This is the code responsible for the submit.

`report.js`

```
    const initialPostData = Object.freeze({
        category: '',
        address: '',
        description: '',
        reporter_first_name: '',
        reporter_last_name: '',
        reporter_email: '',
        reporter_phone: '',
    });

    const [postData, updatePostData] = useState(initialPostData);
    const [postImage1, setPostImage1] = useState({image: null});
    const [postImage2, setPostImage2] = useState({image: null});
    const [postImage3, setPostImage3] = useState({image: null});

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if([e.target.name] == 'reporter_image_1') {
            setPostImage1({
                image: e.target.files[0],
            });
        } else if([e.target.name] == 'reporter_image_2') {
            setPostImage2({
                image: e.target.files[0],
            });
        } else if([e.target.name] == 'reporter_image_3') {
            setPostImage3({
                image: e.target.files[0],
            });
        } else if([e.target.name] == 'category') {
            updatePostData({
                ...postData,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            });
        } else {
            updatePostData({
                ...postData,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
            });
        }
    };


    const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('category', postData.category);
        formData.append('address', postData.address);
        formData.append('description', postData.description);
        formData.append('reporter_first_name', postData.reporter_first_name);
        formData.append('reporter_last_name', postData.reporter_last_name);
        formData.append('reporter_email', postData.reporter_email);       
        formData.append('reporter_image_1', postImage1.image);       
        formData.append('reporter_image_2', postImage2.image);        
        formData.append('reporter_image_3', postImage3.image);       

        const submitForm = await submitReport(formData);
```

And here's the `submitReport` API

`API.js`

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: accessToken
            ? 'JWT ' + accessToken
            : null,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
    }, 
});

// Submit Report Form
const submitReport = async(formData) => {
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.post('reports/', {...formData });
    return data;
}
```

These should be all the files needed to understand what's going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was using the spread operator in the `submitReport` function, but instead I don't need to use it, so:

`API.js`

```
// Submit Report Form
const submitReport = async(formData) => {
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.post('reports/', {...formData });
    return data;
}
```

becomes

```
// Submit Report Form
const submitReport = async(formData) => {
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.post('reports/', formData);
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `parser_classes` attribute on viewset is wrong. If you want to accept JSON format in request body you need to include `JSONParser` in your `parser_classes` attribute.

See the related section from [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#api-reference) in DRF docs.

Comment: I already had tried that, but didn't work, anyway managed to find a solution, I added an answer on how I managed to do it. Thanks for the reply tho!